# Any recommendations to improve this function?

Tags: python

I am very new to working with SQL queries. Any suggestions to improve this bit of code:
(by the way, I really don't care about sql security here; this is a bit of code that will be in a pyexe file connecting to a local sqlite file - so it doesnt make sense to worry about security of the query here).

```
def InitBars(QA = "GDP1POP1_20091224_gdp", QB = "1 pork", reset = False):
    global heights, values
    D, heights, values, max, = [], {}, {}, 0.0001

    if reset: GHolder.remove()

    Q = "SELECT wbcode, Year, "+QA+" FROM DB WHERE commodity='"+QB+"' and "+QA+" IS NOT 'NULL'"  

    for i in cursor.execute(Q): 
        D.append((str(i[0]) + str(i[1]), float(i[2])))
        if float(i[2]) > max: max = float(i[2])

    for (i, n) in D: heights[i] = 5.0 / max * n; values[i] = n
    Gui["YRBox_Slider"].set(0.0)  
    Gui["YRBox_Speed"].set(0.0)
```

---

after following the advices, this is what I got:

```
def InitBars(QA = "GDP1POP1_20091224_gdp", QB = "1 pork", reset = False):
    global heights, values; D, heights, values, max, = [], {}, {}, 0.0001
    if reset: GHolder.remove()

    Q = "SELECT wbcode||Year, %s FROM DB WHERE commodity='%s' and %s IS NOT 'NULL'" % (QA, QB, QA) 
    for a, b in cursor.execute(Q): 
        if float(b) > max: max = float(b)
        values[a] = float(b)

    for i in values: heights[i] = 5.0 / max * values[i]

    Gui["YRBox_Slider"].set(0.0); Gui["YRBox_Speed"].set(0.0)
```

Comment: Do not get used to bad habits. Always care about security.

Comment: given that sqlite3 is part of Python's standard library, you would have to make a better reason for not using its parameterized queries.

Comment: the advice was *not* to put multiple statements in the same line. this include the `if` and its branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one-off script where you totally trust all of the input data and you just need to get a job done, then fine.

If this is part of a system, and this is indicative of the kind of code in it, there are several problems:

1. Don't construct SQL queries by appending strings.  You said that you don't care about security, but this is such a big problem and so easily solved, then really -- you should do it right all of the time
2. This function seems to use and manipulate global state.  Again, if this is a small one-time use script, then go for it -- in systems that span just a few files, this becomes impossible to maintain.
3. Naming conventions --- not following any consistency in capitalization
4. Names of things are not helpful at all.  QA, D, QB, -- QA and QB don't even seem to be the same kind of thing -- one is a field, and the other is a value.
5. All kinds of questionable things are uncommented -- why is max .0001? What the heck is GHolder? What could that loop be doing at the end?  Really, the code should be clearer, but if not, throw the maintainer a bone.

Comment: +1, but I disagree with the first paragraph. There's no reason not to follow these rules in small scripts, and he shouldn't build bad habits. Also, he'll probably reuse the script in the future, even if he doesn't know it now.

Answer (score 1):

- Use more descriptive variable names than `QA` and `QB`.
- Comment the code.
- Don't put multiple statements in the same line
- Try not to use globals. Use member variables instead.
- if QA and QB may come from user input, don't use them to build SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

You should check for SQL injection. Make sure that there's no SQL statement in QA. Also you should probably add slashes if it applies.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use

   ```
   Q = "SELECT wbcode, Year, %s FROM DB WHERE commodity='%s' and %s IS NOT 'NULL'" % (QA, QB, QA)
   ```

instead:

```
Q = "SELECT wbcode, Year, "+QA+" FROM DB WHERE commodity='"+QB+"' and "+QA+" IS NOT 'NULL'"
```

1. Care about security (sql injection).
2. Look at any ORM (SqlAlchemy, for example). It makes things easy :)

Comment: That does nothing to prevent SQL injection.  Set QB to something with a single quote and it's not escaped.  To prevent SQL injection, don't create strings from variables -- use the DB layer to pass in objects as parameters.